# Diagram programation language to recommand?

Tags: latex, drawing, diagram

I am currently looking for a programation language that allows me to create my own diagrams.
You can find attached the types of diagram I would like to create.

- [Speed variator block diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAQ34.png)
- [Antenna signal reception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2a6X.png)
- [Antenna transmission/reception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPbip.png)
- [Algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcxA2.png)

What language could you recommend me ?
I think LaTEX is a good language to do this right ? If so, could you recommend me courses to learn this language ?

Thank you in advance,
kind regards,

Marco

For now, I didn't tried anything except online diagram software, but those don't allow me to do what I would like...

Comment: Have a look at TikZ

Comment: Have look  at https://texample.net/tikz/examples/ for some inspiration with the TikZ-package

Comment: If you can use JavaScript, JointJS could be a good option.
https://www.jointjs.com/demos